# Push an Object Into a complicated arra

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to push an Object into a complicated array I'm thinking about something like that"DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds.push" but I don't succeed to do it. I have an(id, content), and the completed need to be by default false. hope for help I believe that's not too complicated but I can't figure it out. ps: if someone can also help with the delete option I would be happy.

for example, I get (5,test5). I want.

```js
     const DUMMY_PLACES = [
          {
            todos: {
              allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4,],
              byIds: {
                "1": {
                  content: "test1",
                  completed: false,
                },
                "2": {
                  content: "test2",
                  completed: false,
                },
                "3": {
                  content: "test3\\",
                  completed: false,
                },
                "4": {
                  content: "test4",
                  completed: false,
                },
              },
            },
            visibilityFilter: "all",
          },
        ];
```

```js
 const DUMMY_PLACES = [
      {
        todos: {
          allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4,5],
          byIds: {
            "1": {
              content: "test1",
              completed: false,
            },
            "2": {
              content: "test2",
              completed: false,
            },
            "3": {
              content: "test3\\",
              completed: false,
            },
            "4": {
              content: "test4",
              completed: false,
            },
            "5": {
              content: "test5",
              completed: false,
            },
          },
        },
        visibilityFilter: "all",
      },
    ];
```

Comment: what are you trying to push ?

Comment: Where is that `Object` that needs to be pushed in a complicated array ?

Comment: The main problem here seems to be the way you have your data stored.

Comment: I agree with @baao here

Comment: I understand the view of your problem but its a longterm view for under todos and todos in todos.

Comment: @Ethanolle It's not about opinion or views. `todos` should be an array holding what `byIds` does (now wrongly as an object) as an array instead of an object, and `allIds` is unneccessary completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here take a look at the `addTodo` function which creates a new instance of the `todoList` with a new element added to the end of it. And it also modifies the list of `Ids`. I've commented almost every line, so it should be pretty straightforward.

```
let todoList = [
  {
    todos: {
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      byIds: {
        "1": {
          content: "test1",
          completed: false,
        },
        "2": {
          content: "test2",
          completed: false,
        },
        "3": {
          content: "test3",
          completed: false,
        },
        "4": {
          content: "test4",
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    },
    visibilityFilter: "all",
  },
];

let addTodo = (sourceArray, el) => {
  // Create a copy of an original array
  let targetArray = [];
  Object.assign(targetArray, sourceArray);

  let todos = targetArray[0].todos;

  // Calculate the Id for a new element
  let newId = Object.keys(todos.byIds).length + 1;

  // Add new Id to the `allIds` list
  todos.allIds.push(newId);

  // Create a new element
  todos.byIds[newId] = {
    content: el,
    completed: false
  }

  return targetArray;
}

todoList = addTodo(todoList, 'test5');
todoList = addTodo(todoList, 'test6');
todoList = addTodo(todoList, 'test7');

console.log(JSON.stringify(todoList));
```

And the output should be:

```
[
  {
    "todos":{
      "allIds":[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
      ],
      "byIds":{
        "1":{
          "content":"test1",
          "completed":false
        },
        "2":{
          "content":"test2",
          "completed":false
        },
        "3":{
          "content":"test3",
          "completed":false
        },
        "4":{
          "content":"test4",
          "completed":false
        },
        "5":{
          "content":"test5",
          "completed":false
        },
        "6":{
          "content":"test6",
          "completed":false
        },
        "7":{
          "content":"test7",
          "completed":false
        }
      }
    },
    "visibilityFilter":"all"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks encapsulation. Best approach here would be to create a new class and create a setter for this.

EDIT with example:

```js
class UserTodo
{
    constructor( visibilityFilter = 'all' )
    {
        this._visibilityFilter  = visibilityFilter;
        this._byIds             = new Map();
    }
    /**
     * @details Add a todo with the content text
     */
    addTodo( title, content )
    {
        const value = {
            content,
            completed: false
        }
        this._byIds.set( title, value );
    }

    /**
     * @Details Decide if you want to get the entire object or just the content here
     */
    getTodo( title )
    {
        return this._byIds.get( title );
    }

    completeTodo( title )
    {
        this._byIds.get( title ).completed  = true;
    }

    /**
     * @details As a bonus on how to delete a specific todo
     */
    deleteTodo( title )
    {
        this._byIds.delete( title );
    }

    /**
     * @details this will return allIds from the example
     */
    getAllIds()
    {
        return Array.from( this._byIds.keys() );
    }

    /**
     * @details this will return visibilityFilter from the example
     */
    getVisibility()
    {
        return this._visibilityFilter;
    }

    // Implement other getters
}

// Why is this an array even?
const DUMMY_PLACES  = [];
DUMMY_PLACES.push( new UserTodo( 'all' ) );

const toDoTitle = 'Some Title';

// Add a new todo
DUMMY_PLACES[0].addTodo( toDoTitle, 'Do Something' );

// Check that the todo is added
console.log( DUMMY_PLACES[0].getTodo( toDoTitle ) );

// Complete it
DUMMY_PLACES[0].completeTodo( toDoTitle );

// Check that it is completed
console.log( DUMMY_PLACES[0].getTodo( toDoTitle ) );
```

Comment: Yes and my answer stays the same. This code need better encapsulation. You are trying to do a rather complex operation on a very complex object. And objects SHOULD NOT be used in this way. 

Check my Edit see if you prefer that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this

```js
const DUMMY_PLACES = [ { todos: { allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4], byIds: { "1": { content: "test1", completed: false, }, "2": { content: "test2", completed: false, }, "3": { content: "test3\\", completed: false, }, "4": { content: "test4", completed: false, }, }, }, visibilityFilter: "all", }, ];

function pushObject(id, content) {
  DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.allIds.push(id);
  DUMMY_PLACES[0].todos.byIds[id] = { ...content, completed: false };
}
pushObject(5, { content: "test5" });
console.dir(DUMMY_PLACES);
```